# Using GKImagePicker to crop photo

Tags: ios, photo

I want to crop a photo that is taken in the app and then save. I am using the GKImagePicker so that I can do this but if I use the code below even though I push the take photo button in my app it shows me the photo library which I pick to crop.  I do not want to do this and just want to crop my photo which I have taken in the app.

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    self.imagePicker = [[GKImagePicker alloc] init];
    self.imagePicker.cropSize = CGSizeMake(320, 320);
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;


    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.imagePicker.imagePickerController animated:YES];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: Dude would you please add more explanation what you want to do, Do you need to corp the image directly after taking it from the Cam without opening the photo library?

Comment: YES sorry about less explanation..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last line in your code:

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];// remove
```

and give it a try ;)

You can also check [this](https://github.com/gekitz/GKImagePicker/issues/5).

Comment: It dosen't crop after taking the photo.  It moves but it dosen't scale it properly